# some confusion over calling drawchart in google chart on click of a button

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-visualization

I am trying to generate column chart on click of a button.When I click on the button drawchart() is called but no chart is created on screen.I examined the function by using alerts and found that data.addRow(array1[i],array2[j]) doesnt execute.The both arrays contain values extracted from json

Also when I remove this button and call function drawChart() on page load,I can see that only chart is created but no columns are drawn to it as there are no values in both the arrays.Any kind of help is really appreciated.

My code

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function loadJSON()
  {

      alert("hello");
      alert(category);
      alert(subcat);
      alert(subdem);
     var data_file = "https://tc.api.tibco.com:43/TopOne/v1/"+category+"/"+subcat+"/"+subdem;
     alert("abc")
     var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
        alert("in try");
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{ alert("in try1");
           http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e) {
           try{ alert("in try2");
              http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }catch (e){
              // Something went wrong
              alert("Your browser broke!");
              return false;
           }
        }
     }
     http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
         if(http_request.readyState ==1){ alert("1");}
         if(http_request.readyState ==2){ alert("2");}
         if(http_request.readyState ==3){ alert("3");}
         if(http_request.readyState ==4){ alert("4");}
        if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
        {
          // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
          var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
            alert(http_request.responseText);
            alert(jsonObj);
          // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
          // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.

         //alert( jsonObj.Category.CategoryName);
         //alert(jsonObj.Category.CategoryName.Demographies.DemographyName);

          //document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML = jsonObj.country;
          alert(jsonObj.Category[0].SubCategory[0].Demographies[0].Items[0].Name);
          alert(jsonObj.Category[0].SubCategory[0].Demographies[0].Items[1].Name);
          for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
              {
              array1[i] = jsonObj.Category[0].SubCategory[0].Demographies[0].Items[i].Name;
              array2[i] = jsonObj.Category[0].SubCategory[0].Demographies[0].Items[i].SalesCount;

              }
          for(i=0;i<10;i++)
              {
              alert(array1[i]+" "+array2[i]);
              }
        }
     }
     http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("accept","application/json");

     http_request.send();
     }




  function drawChart(){

    alert("hello");

     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'name');
     data.addColumn('number', 'salescount');
     alert("ggg");
     for(i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
            data.addRow([array1[i], array2[i]]);






        var options = {
          title: "Movies",
          width: 600,height:400
          //hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('lowerRightDiv'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
  } 
  function initialize(){

            $("button.charts").click(function() {

                    drawChart();
            });
        }
       google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
       google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

      </script>
```

My code for the created button are

```
<button class="charts" onclick="initialize();"style="left:400px;">Generate charts</button>
```

Comment: Why do you have an 'onclick' attribute and a `click` binding using jquery?  I think you usually only want one or the other... Also, did you ever call the function to actually load the JSON?  It's not shown anywhere, so you might be trying to make a chart with data that doesn't exist.

Comment: I APOLOGIZE, I have kept the button which calls loadJSON () FUNCTION <button onclick="loadJSON ();"> LOADJSON </button> this i have kept a button jus for testing. But also after calling JSON it doesnt execute

Comment: Sounds like this is a variable scope issue.  Add the line `console.log(array1, array2);` to the start of `drawChart`, then open the page in Chrome and view the developer's console (ctrl+shift+j to open in Windows).  What is output in the console when you run `drawChart`?